# Excel Macro - making next 2 cells blank if cell has a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to adapt a macro in an excel sheet so that if column AC = "FT" then AD and AE should be cleared.

I have tried searching for an answer but unable to find anything that works.

Thanks

Comment: have you made any code attempts ? you want to search all the cells in Column AC and see if one of them equals "FT"

Comment: Post the macro you are trying to adapt. Explain where you are stuck or what 's not working. Edit your post for that. Don't post that in a comment. You can post a comment when you're done, so we get notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then try the following code in the worksheet code module where you put your data.

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow   'Set the value of i as a starting point depends on your first data is located
    If Cells(i, "AC").Value = "FT" Then
        Range(Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "AE")).Clear     'Alternatively .Value = "" or .ClearContents
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look around the site. We don't encourage requests to write code for OPs. We encourage OPs to post what they have tried, so we can help them learn and understand. This site is not a free coding service, so please hold back on posting code where the OP has not made an effort to ask a good question and has not posted their code, even after prompting. Yes, you may get a few rep points but it's a cheap win.

Comment: @teylyn On Math SE we don't mind to answer a bad question just because we find that problem interesting or we just want to answer it for getting few points and I don't think it's a cheap win. Well, I guess the culture on SO is quite different. I apologize for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Yes, SO is different.